# Sepetate 2 glutinous arrow header in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

Hi my arrow like following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSdQn.png

Arrow on the red marked is glutinous.

How do I divide it?

---

**add code**

https://www.codepile.net/pile/XKvOwL3A

Comment: Use [headport](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headport) and [tailport](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:tailport) edge attributes to adjust where the arrow starts and points. If you'd provided code for your example I could've shown you a specific solution.

Comment: OK, I post my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation fastest fix would be to add `nodesep = 0.15` graph attribute (right after `digraph {` statement). This attribute adjusts the minimal distance between the nodes in one rank. This results in:

[image]

Also you may play with `headport` and `tailport` attributes, as I suggested in the comment. Shortcut for them is to add a colon after node when you are defining edge.

If you replace `TR_Client_Data -> idle` with `TR_Client_Data -> idle:e` you will get this result:

[image]

Edges are crossed, but they are apart.

---

Also I've noticed that you define node attributes in a wrong way: keyword `node` defines **global attributes** for all nodes in the graph (or subgraph). If you want to specify attributes for a single node, place them after node definition.

e.g.

**WRONG:**

```
node [
    shape = point, 
    fontsize = 12
  ] start_point;
```

**CORRECT:**

```
start_point [
    shape = point, 
    fontsize = 12
  ];
```